# Clickable Image in CSS

Tags: html, css, image, hyperlink

I am wondering if it is possible in CSS to make an image clickable to a certain point. Like only the part inside of its edges when my image is not square or circle.

This image:
[image]

updated the image..

Comment: why dont you make the image itself  using CSS?..see https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/ ..

Comment: Also you could use is **HTML `map`**

Comment: Or use SVG for images like that

Comment: check http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_areamap

Comment: Also have a look at https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/map

Answer (score 0):

In CSS, your best bet is to try to manipulate an anchor using [CSS transform properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transforms/Using_CSS_transforms), but I doubt you'll get the desired effect. Knowing what the image is and the clickable areas might give people on this site a better idea of what the best solutions is using the transform property.

However using HTML, you can achieve this effect by using an [image map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map). This is the recommended solution but it doesn't meet the CSS requirement.

2 other options are [canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API) or [SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG) but I won't go into these in detail on this answer.